# Changing the batch color in the Fluid Library

Tags: anylogic

I am curious to know how to change the batch color dynamically when using the Fluid Library. Say I am using a fluidSelectInput block. I want to set the output to a certain color when coming from input 1 and a different color when coming from input 2. I have access to the batch object in *On new batch at input 1*  but it is not clear how to change the color here.

I have tried something along the lines of ...

((MyBatch)batch).setColor(Color.red);

.....

but this is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new batch coming out from a fluidSelectInput block... The logic is different in the way that to input1 and input2 you already have 2 different fluids coming... so why would you want to change the batch color at the fluidSelectInput when you can change it in the sources that go to the fluidSelectInput? The fluidSelectInput is just a pathway, it's not an element that can change the characteristics of your fluid.

The actions On new Batch at input work to identify new batches coming in, and not to create new batches on the output.

The code you are using is correct, but the whole logic is wrong so you have to rethink your problem or ask your question in a different way. Remember to set your blocks with "custom batch" in order to be able to change the batch effectively.

Conclusion... what you want to use really is the fluidMerge instead... in that block you can control your exit batch

Comment: You are correct. I meant actually fluidSelectOutput. Yes, I understand that these blocks do no create anything. I actually do create my batches upstream, then along the way, they come into a fluidSelectOuput block. For the moment, choice between the 2 outputs is based on a probability and I wanted to visualize the batches after they have passed the block. Say, going through output1 - >red, and going through output2 -> blue